# What is spy.js often seen in the console

Tags: spy

Sorry if this is obvious but i cannot find a straight forward answer on the net so far...

What exactly is spy.js?

I keep seeing it in the console sometimes of firefox or chrome... is it somehow related to spry.js

I understand that spry is a js framework from adobe though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spy.js is file within a firebug based development tool meant for debugging a website with nice tools (http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.4/content/firebug/spy.js?r=2796)

My guess is that spry, an ajax framework, is at times calling some jsonp that uses functions defined inside of spy.js, thus throwing a console error for the missing file if it wasn't properly loaded.

Checking that all of your dependencies are properly loaded will likely solve the problem. But i'm just guessing.

Comment: Ahhh... ok that makes a lot of sense. I am however not using the ajax framework spry (to my knowledge). I use either my own js functions on projects or jquery. But i often see the spy error when using either..